# How do I return a C array of strings to be used in Vala code?

Tags: arrays, c, string, vala

I'm using Vala to create a Linux app.

To parse JSON, I want to use C, because Vala library is complicated for me and, and it is able to run C functions. The function should return an array of strings that will be used inside Vala code.

The main problem is that unlike Vala, C does not really know what is an array of strings is. I found that the array of strings can be declared as a `char*[]`.

I tried to:

- Use a returned `char*[]` as an array of strings in Vala, but that did not help.
- Convert returned `char* []` from C to a string array in Vala directly, but I was given a lot of compilation errors.

I've made an assumption that `char*[]` in C, and `char*[]` in Vala, work differently.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of your attempt. Make sure to include your command lines to build and the error messages.

Comment: Please provide some ```sample codes``` and show exactly what you tried so far and what you achieved at this point. No one can help you by reading what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the what you want do; Vala is actually quite flexible in how it binds to C APIs since it was designed to be used with C APIs which don't know anything about Vala.

My suggestion would be to write the API you want in Vala, then use `valac -C foo.vala` to transpile the Vala to C code, where you can easily see the API it expects.  Basically, though, for a Vala API like `string[] foo()`, the expected C signature would be something like `gchar** foo(gint* array_length)`.